# QTP 11 with Flex 3.0

Tags: automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

We have requirement in our project where we need to run our automated tests on QTP 11 version for an application based on Flex 3.0. We need SWC files for this. 
Also please let me know if QTP 11 is compatible with Flex 3.0. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: QTP 11 is really obsolete, you should really upgrade. The license for QTP allows for upgrades so there should be no problem to move to the latest version of UFT.

Comment: The license only allows if you have an active service agreement with them. Else you will have to start afresh. My organisation missed renewing the agreements and we had to renegotiate the new licences for UFT 14.

Comment: @Motti but will that support Flex 3.0 application

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall